# stub.getQueryResult(queryString) How to get more then 100 result

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, stub

```
let resultsIterator = await ctx.stub.getQueryResult(JSON.stringify(queryString));
```

This function is in stub only return 100 result. I want more than 100. how to archive this?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show how you are iterating through the returned iterator to get your results, please provide more detail about the code you use to get each individual entry

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You can check your query limit in `config/core.yaml` in a `fabric-sample` folder. If you want more data then you have to use the **CouchDB pagination** concept. And change the query limit in **core.yaml** file. All chaincode queries are bound by **totalQueryLimit** (default 100000) from **core.yaml**.

Here I recommend these links.

1. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/couchdb_as_state_database.html
2. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AzcVjVbuvZGRozfNe3ksIpK-cBMlhhbGOUZhg2bzPW8/edit

Hope it will help you :)